# ssh needs a restart before permitting remote access with rsa key

Tags: ssh

I can ssh between two machines using rsa keys.

When both machines are rebooted. I can connect from Ubuntu 14.04 to  Debian 7.8, VirtualBox, Win 8.1.

However, I can not connect the other way without first restarting the ssh server on Ubuntu. Even though ssh was already running.

note: when i enabled password logins, i could access both sides without the restart.

edit: response to comment

This is the error message I get from my VirtualBox machine.

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.x port 22: Connection timed out
```

No message in logs /var/log/auth.log with level DEBUG

As mentioned previously, if I do

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

on Ubuntu. I can then connect from the VirtualBox without a problem.

Comment: What do the logs  say on the Ubuntu system when trying to connect. Is here any relevant information in the logs if you increase the log verbosity to DEBUG?  What error messages do  you see on the client side?

Comment: @Iain I have updated my question with the details you requested.

Comment: I have a similar problem once a vpn-connection is established. The first ssh-connection always times out. I watched it with `wireshark`, the syn-packets are simply not answered. To speed this up, I ping the host until a reply is received, after that `ssh` gets a connection.

Comment: I tried pinging both ways before trying to ssh and that did not change anything.... Firewalls are down....  ssh is running and listening on port 22....  i can connect locally but not remotely before ssh restart....  so why do i need to restart ssh for it to work....  I don't mind adding a restart command in a system boot up script. Any ideas on the best place to put it.